# How to break on assembly instruction at a given address in gdb?

Tags: assembly, gdb

```
0x0000000000400448 <main+0>:    push   %rbp
0x0000000000400449 <main+1>:    mov    %rsp,%rbp
0x000000000040044c <main+4>:    mov    $0x6,%eax
0x0000000000400451 <main+9>:    leaveq 
0x0000000000400452 <main+10>:   retq
```

I tried:

```
breaki 0x0000000000400448
```

but it seems that there not such command.

Does gdb have such a feature?

Comment: why `breaki`? is that a typo?

Comment: @Blauhirn Perhaps as a supposed analogy with `stepi` and `nexti`, which are used for single-stepping at the instruction level.

Answer (score 216, accepted):

try `break *0x0000000000400448`

Comment: Probably because * is required to specify an address.
see http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Specify-Location.html#Specify-Location

Comment: And of course you can remove the leading zeroes and abbreviate `break`, give `b *0x400448`.

Comment: To disambiguate with function or data named `0x0000000000400448` (unusual as that would be!)

Comment: @compile-fan
break *address
Set a breakpoint at address address. You can use this to set breakpoints in parts of your program which do not have debugging information or source files.
https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_node/gdb_28.html
I was debugging a assembly code and reached here for the same question which you asked.

Answer (score 88):

Another way:

`break *main+4`

This will add a breakpoint at `0x000000000040044c`
I think this is easier than writing the whole address!